# Air Resistance in Taylor Classical Mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

In Taylor's *Classical Mechanics*, he offers up a quick little example to get the reader acquainted with different scenarios in which air resistance approximated as a linear and/or quadratic function is important.

I've provided, attached, the example that I'm confused about. Essentially, how is it that we can conclude that in the case of an object with small $D$, if the ratio of quadratic and linear terms is near unity then we cannot ignore air resistance but if $D$ is large and this occurs then we may. Now, I generally get that the distinction between the two cases is that, in the former, $v$ must be large in order to achieve this, whereas in the latter case $v$ must be small. *Ceteris paribus*, if $v$ is larger then the drag force will be larger. But, in the former case, $D$ is small so shouldn't the drag force thus be small too (and in the second case even though $v$ is small $D$ is large - again, so that the ratio of quadratic and linear terms is approximately 1).

Essentially, why is it that when $v$ is small and $D$ is large we can ignore air resistance but when $v$ is large and $D$ is small we cannot? To me, they would seem to be different effects that achieve the same thing. According to equations (2.3) and (2.5), the two terms seem to be symmetrical in $v$ and $D$.

[image: Relevant Equations]

[image: Example]

[image: Ex 2]

Comment: Hi 1729_SR, it's against our rules to post images of text you want to quote. Could you please type it out instead so it can be indexed by search engines? For formulas, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can compare both forces to inertia to see why. Note that $F_{\text{quad}} \sim D^2v^2$, whereas $F_{\text{lin}} \sim Dv $, while inertia is $P \sim D^3 v$. Thus

$$\frac{P}{F_{\text{quad}}} \sim \frac{D}{v}$$
which is large in the limit of $v \rightarrow 0$ ($F_{\text{quad}}$ cannot stop easily the body); while
$$\frac{P}{F_{\text{lin}}} \sim D^2$$
which is small in the limit $D\rightarrow 0$ ($F_{\text{lin}}$ will stop the body very quickly).

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I think it's really helpful and I'm just about ready to give it a checkmark. If I can though, I'm hoping to quickly confirm what you've described above. I'll refer to your first equation as (1) and the second as (2). In the problem, Taylor says that if $D$ is large and $v$ is small enough to make $F_{lin}$ and $F_{quad}$ of the same order, then we can ignore them. This means (1) and (2) are large above. On the other hand, for small $D$, a large $v$ is required to make them of the same order and so (1) and (2) are each small. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: No, because imagine $F_{\text{lin}} = \alpha Dv$ and $F_{\text{quad}} = \beta D^2v^2$. Then you have $\alpha / \beta \sim Dv$, which means that $P/(F_{\text{lin}} + F_{\text{quad}}) \sim D^3 v / (\beta D^2v^2 + \beta D^2v^2) \sim D/v$, which is large in this context.